# AWS Reserved Instances - Windows Server Criteria

Tags: amazon-ec2, aws-reserved-instances

We have a two R3.4xlarge instances running MS-SQL on a windows server.

One is reserved and other is on demand. We currently start-stop between those instances (only one of them is running at a time), to avail RI benefits.

Can we launch both these instances at the same time as a scale-down R3.2xlarge instances and get the RI savings from one R3.4xlarge? Are there any RI limitations for Windows platform?

thanks
-Ravi

Answer (score 1):

While that feature does exist for Linux/Unix instances, this does not apply to Windows Instances.

> Instance size flexibility does not apply to Reserved Instances that are purchased for a specific Availability Zone, bare metal instances, Reserved Instances with dedicated 
>    tenancy, and **Reserved Instances for Windows**, Windows with SQL Standard, Windows with 
>    SQL Server Enterprise, Windows with SQL Server Web, RHEL, and SLES.

https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSEC2/latest/UserGuide/apply_ri.html

Comment: Thank you Adam. We heard about this limitation for windows but were not able to land on this docs/user guide link you shared. Appreciate it.